# How can you customize on a multisite?

Tags: multisite

How do multisites have the ability to customize the look of the theme (menu color, style, etc.) without changing it for everyone else.

Where are these separate files stored?

Comment: Do you mean that the theme is customized on each site in a Multisite network, or that the theme is customized for each user on a specific site? If the former, have a look at the [Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the [Theme Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/), it appears that theme modifications are stored as `theme_mod`s which can be access using [`get_theme_mod( $mod_name )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/) or (if you want to grab them all) [`get_theme_mods()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mods/).

Peeking into the source of `get_theme_mods()`, I see that the mods are stored in the site's `options` table as `theme_mod_$mod_name`. So the theme modifications are stored in the database, not in any files.

### References

- [Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/)
- [`get_theme_mod()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/)
- [`get_theme_mods()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mods/)
- [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

Answer (score 0):

You can create child themes to add modifications to the design of a specific website from your multisite network. These modifications are stored in the folder of your child theme.